# How to fetch data from two tables(one-to-many relations) using Hibernate Createcriteria

Tags: hibernate-mapping

How to fetch data from two tables based upon User id ?
**********************************Role Class********************************************

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "IUC_CON_USER_ROLE_MAP")
    public class Role {
        @Id
        @Column(name="F_ROLE_MAP_ID")
        int rolemap;

        @Column(name="F_ROLE_ID")
        int roleid;


        @OneToMany(mappedBy="role",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        Set<User>  F_USER_ID;
```

************************************User class**************************************

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "IUC_CON_USER")
    public class User implements Serializable {


        @Id
        @Column(name = "F_USER_ID")
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "F_USER_NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "F_USER_PWD")
        private String pwd;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="F_USER_ID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
        private Role role;

                 ----------setter and getter for properties
    }
```

External edit:
Criteria creation code:

```
DetachedCriteria uCrit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class, "user");
uCrit.add(Restrictions.eq("user.id", 5));
uCrit.setProjection(Projections.property("user.id"));
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Role.class, "role");
criteria.add(Property.forName("role.F_USER_ID").in(uCrit));
List lt1 = criteria.getExecutableCriteria(getSession()).list();
```

Comment: you want to fetch `User` along with the associated `Role`?

Comment: @Debojit 'yes i want user along with Role'

Answer (score 0):

use `createAlias`

```
criteria.createAlias("propertiy_of_main_entity", "aliastName");
```

For me this fetches entities asociated with root entity via some entity property name;

in your case something like

```
createAlias("F_USER_ID", "roleUsers");
```

should do.

Anyway why ins't your field name following commong naming doctrine for Java? **WHY_IS_IT_UPPERCASED_WITH_DASHES_LIKE_CONSTANTS_?**

All in all everything is explained in [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-from-fetch). If alias won't work, than fetch associations like in examples from Hibernate documentation under link I provided.

Comment: 'Please if u don't mind will u elaborate with the above code '

Comment: @Antonisss i getting this error:-Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: F_USER_ID of: com.basu.User

Comment: i think we have to mention id  bec we have to use class property name but not the table column

Comment: Than change it to proper property (getter without `get` part).
Moreover I don't know how are you creating your criteria so how should I know what is your root entity? Did you read documentation to whitch I provided link for?

Comment: inspite of using id still i getting following errror:-Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: not an association: id

Comment: Yes, like i wrote in answer it is property name - one of your fields have such name - CAPITALIZED ONE.

Comment: Better paste code where you are creating criteria... You wrote that you want to fetch ROLES with USERS not the other way around (yeah, there is a BIG difference if we are talking about Criteria API). Your error suggest that your root entity is USER, not ROLE

Comment: DetachedCriteria uCrit = DetachedCriteria.forClass( User.class, "user" ); 
  uCrit.add( Restrictions.eq("user.id", 5 ) ); 
  uCrit.setProjection( Projections.property("user.id") ); 
  DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Role.class, "role");
  
  criteria.add( Property.forName("role.F_USER_ID").in( uCrit ) ); 
  List lt1=criteria.getExecutableCriteria( getSession() ).list();

Comment: Paste it to your question as edit, not here because it is totally unreadable.

Comment: Role is parent entity and User is Child entity

Comment: And your criteria says you are threating them the other way around... But thats still fine, because you have mapped your assiciation bidirectionaly

Comment: will u suggest me proper Criteria Code for that so that i retrive data from two tables(user,Role) based upon user id

Answer (score 0):

You can use below series of statements to fetch `User` along with the `Role`:

```
int userId = 1;
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("role", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", userId));
User user = (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

The default fetching strategy of Hibernate is to fetch the associations lazily, which you need to override at runtime in code, if you want the associations (here the `Role`) to be fetched along with `User`. The third statement is doing this overriding by seting the fetch mode to `JOIN`. This statement `FetchMode.JOIN` overrides the default behavior, so that `Role` will be fetched along with the `User`.

Comment: @Saikai when i execute above code i getting error and moreover in query which is generated in console User.id is not mapping with Role.F_user_id instead Role_map_id is mapping with User.id.

Comment: but the Criteria creation code you have given is different from the code in my answer. have you tried my code?

Comment: @Saikai actually there is a row in User table with F_User_id =1 but i getting following error:-Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.basu.Role#1]

Comment: Yes i tried ur code also  but i getting error which i posted above

Comment: please if u don't mind will u modify my Criteria Creation code so that i can retrive data from both table based upon User.id

Comment: the column `F_USER_ID` in User table should refer to a primary key value in the role table? do you have a row in role table with primary key `1`?

Comment: actually i will tell my table scenarios.User table has F_USER_ID as a primary key and Role Table  have a column F_USER_ID which is foreign key and which is reffering Primary key of User table. and i have to map these two tables . is my mapping code is correct bec i am little bit confuse

Comment: i am afraid your mapping is not correct. As you want to have many Users mapped to a single Role, you need to create a foreign key in the User table (let it be `F_ROLE_ID`) to refer to the primary key in the `Role` table. Change the `joinColumn` annotation of `Role role` property to this `@JoinColumn(name="F_ROLE_ID",..)`. And you don't need to have any foreign key in the role table to refer to user table.

Comment: by doing above modification will my Criteria creation Code will work

Comment: make the changes and try the code i have given. It will surely work.